# GCP Managed Service Account is not created (for Cloud Asset API)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-cloud-iam

I have enabled the API `Cloud Asset API (cloudasset.googleapis.com)`, but It didn't create the GCP managed service account `service-{projectNumber}@gcp-sa-cloudasset.iam.gserviceaccount.com`. I have read it at multiple place that GCP is suppose to create that account.

I have tried to enable/disable the API multiple times but still no luck.

If anyone knows the workaround, Please let me know :-)

Answer (score 11):

The documentation should be updated, but the service account is not created when you activate the API, but when you run an export.  So if you run an export of the assets, the service account will appear.

If, for a reason, you can't run an export (e.g. when you want to create an asset feed to monitor for changes), you can run the following command:

`gcloud beta services identity create --service=cloudasset.googleapis.com --project=PROJECT_ID`

In Terraform, I created a `null_resource` that does the trick.

Comment: I have a hard time tracking down literature (GCP documentation or third party blogs) that explain the difference between `gcloud iam service-accounts create ...` and `gcloud beta services identity create ...` Could someone explain?

Comment: This is the right answer. I've got no idea why the service account isn't created when the API is activated. But the [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/monitoring-asset-changes#:~:text=The%20service%20account%20will%20be%20created%20by%20calling%20the%20API%20once%2C%20or%20you%20can%20use%20the%20following%20command%3A) stated that the service account will be created by calling the API once, or you can use the command that @Bjorn121 posted.

Comment: You can now use the terraform resource `google_project_service_identity` to get the service identity email account.

Answer (score 3):

It exists! But it has no permission. Simply go to IAM page, click on +ADD. Fill the email with the Cloud Asset service account email: `service-{projectNumber}@gcp-sa-cloudasset.iam.gserviceaccount.com`. And add it, at least the role `Cloud Asset Service Agent`. Save.

Comment: I have already done that it doesn't recognise the email.

`Email addresses and domains must be associated with an active Google Account, G Suite account, or Cloud Identity account.`

Comment: Even with the API activated? If so, contact the support.

Comment: Check if the "e-mail" you paste contains a whitespace character in the beginning or end.

A common issue is when you copy the service account from the member column from the IAM list of another project, a tab character is added on the end. When pasting the into the "New Member" input, GCP will suggest the account for you, but even if you click the suggested account, it will keep the tab at the end...

Comment: @Andreas L that was my exact problem. I had a space in the service account long email at the end and got this error.
`Email addresses and domains must be associated with an active Google Account, G Suite account, or Cloud Identity account.`   I removed the space and it worked. thanks

Comment: To see the service agents in the list, don't forget to tick "Include Google-provided role grants" on the IAM page

Answer (score 0):

Having a similar problem, I could see the service account in the form of `service-{projectNumber}@gcp-sa-cloudasset.iam.gserviceaccount.com` was indeed created, but I could not assign a role to it, as I got this confusing (wrong) error you got (`mail addresses and domains must be associated with an active Google Account, G Suite account, or Cloud Identity account.`).

I discovered there is a new policy in town that prohibits the use of cross-project service account permissions: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/restricting-service-accounts#disable_cross_project_service_accounts.

`gcloud beta resource-manager org-policies disable-enforce iam.disableCrossProjectServiceAccountUsage --organization <org_id>` should solve it.

Answer (score -1):

Apart from running the command provided in the accepted answer I had to do the following:

1. Go to IAM and check 'Include Google-provided role grants'

[image]

2. Search for 'gcp-sa-cloudasset.iam.gserviceaccount.com'. Click on edit image and the role Storage Object Admin role If it doesn't have it.

[image]