# "ERROR: (gcloud.asset.export) User does not have permission" only when authenticated with a service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-asset-inventory

I'm trying to export project assets with [Google Cloud Asset Inventory](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/overview) and `gcloud` command (version 314.0.0) **authenticated with a service account** :

```sh
# 1. authenticate with service account my-service-account@$PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/path/to/my/key.json

# 2. export assets to BQ
gcloud asset export \
    --project=$PROJECT_ID \
    --bigquery-table=projects/$PROJECT_ID/datasets/$DATASET_ID/tables/$TABLE_ID \
    --output-bigquery-force \
    --content-type=resource
```

And got the following error :

> ERROR: (gcloud.asset.export) User [my-service-account@$PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com] does not have permission to access project [$PROJECT_ID:exportAssets] (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission

My service account have the following roles on `$PROJECT_ID` :

- `roles/cloudasset.viewer`
- `roles/bigquery.jobUser`
- `roles/bigquery.dataEditor`

Note that `gcloud asset export` **works when I'm logged with my own personal account**, which have the same roles as my service account.

Adding `--verbosity=debug` flag to `gcloud` does not add additional info :

> apitools.base.py.exceptions.HttpForbiddenError: HttpError accessing https://cloudasset.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$PROJECT_ID:exportAssets?alt=json

with the following content :

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

I don't understand the difference between being logged with the service account (`gcloud auth activate-service-account`) and my own personal account (`gcloud auth login`), both should work since I have exactly the same permissions.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the export work if you restrict the asset types with the `--asset-types` gcloud flag? Does it work if you give the service account permissions on storage and try the export to GCS instead of BQ? Just throwing some ideas on how to restrict the possible root causes of a permission error...

Comment: @Jofre thanks for your comment. It does not work with `--asset-types` but it seems to work on GCS. I just needed to add `service-$PROJECT_ID_OF_BUCKET@gcp-sa-cloudasset.iam.gserviceaccount.com` as storage admin. I'll try to do the same with BigQuery.

Comment: Yup, that issue seems documented here: https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/faq#how_do_i_export_assets_to_tables_that_dont_belong_to_the_current_project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an opened investigation on this issue:

[permission denied error when exporting asset to GCS or BigQuery](https://issuetracker.google.com/171179807)

It seems that you have to impersonate the built-in service account `service-xxxxxxxx@gcp-sa-cloudasset.iam.gserviceaccount.com` and to add the `Storage Admin` role to it.

Also you will have to add the roles `roles/bigquery.jobUser` and `roles/bigquery.dataEditor` to the service account `service-xxxxxxxx@gcp-sa-cloudasset.iam.gserviceaccount.com`  where `xxxxxx` is the project id.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, I had to add `service-xxxxxxxx@gcp-sa-cloudasset.iam.gserviceaccount.com` (`xxxxxxxx` = project ID of my service account) the roles `roles/bigquery.jobUser` and `roles/bigquery.dataEditor`). Could you update your answer with that additional info so I can accept it ? Thanks.

Comment: ok, I updated my answer. I am happy that your issue was solved.

Comment: also, service account is not auto-created. see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63785247/gcp-managed-service-account-is-not-created-for-cloud-asset-api